# How To Type Into Textfield on webpage using MonoMac? (WebBrowser Control Alternative)

Tags: webview, browser, monomac

Im used to developing on .net so decided to try MonoMac, but unfortunately the WebBrowser control in .net isn't available in Mono.

Ive added a webview, and Ive figured out how to navigate:

```
wbWebView.MainFrameUrl = "http://www.linkedin.com";
```

Now for the life of me I can't figure out how to do these kinds of things I used to be able to do in .net:

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", "myemaillogin@btinternet.com")
```

or stuff like this in .net:

```
For Each link As HtmlElement In wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        If link.GetAttribute("href").Contains("twitter") Then
            Dim hyperlink As String = link.GetAttribute("href")
            ListBox1.Items.Add(hyperlink)
        End If
    Next
```

(where wb is the webbrowser control in the above 2 examples)

Any ideas?

Ive tried looking at the xml approach, but either Im doing it wrong, but isn't really working for me.  Its a shame there isn't the webbrowser control in mono!

Thanks very much for all your help.

ps. I know my .net examples are VB, but the same applies to C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
- (IBAction)btnDoStuff:(NSButton *)sender {
    [[[self myWebView] mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/"]]];

    [[self myWebView] setEditable:YES];
}

- (IBAction)btnCoolCode:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    DOMDocument *myDomDocument = [[self myWebView] mainFrameDocument];

    DOMNodeList *myList = [myDomDocument getElementsByTagName:@"a"];

    int numElements = [myList length];

    for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++) {
        [myArray addObject:(DOMHTMLElement *)[myList item:i]];
    }

    self.lblOutput.stringValue = [[myArray objectAtIndex:7] innerText];
```